# While loop for detecting full cells

Tags: c#, excel, loops, while-loop, cells

I'm doing a little application using c# and excel.
i want te create new lines on the sheet but not on the lines where there is already something written.
To do that my idea was to look the consecutive cells of the first column and write on the first which is not full.

Here is the code

```
int i = 1;
while (oSheet.Cells[i, 1] != null){
    i = i + 1;
}

oSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "First Name";
```

It's easy but when i'm trying to do that i got the following message :

> Error : exception de hresult 0x800A01A8 line:mscorlib

When i try with if, i can write on the sheet so i don't know where is the problem.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: When i put it inside the loop, i got a loop which never end

Comment: maybe you need to add the row/column before you may fill the value

Comment: You will loop forever if all the cells exist. You should be checking the content of the cells not.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it this way:

```
int i = 1;
while (oSheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString()).Value2 != null) i++;
oSheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString()).Value2 = "FirstName";
```

EDIT: This is the way OP tried to do it:

```
    int i = 1;
    while ((ws.Cells[i, 1] as Range).Value2 != null) i++;
    (ws.Cells[i, 1] as Range).Value2 = "First NAme";
```

Either way it works

The problem OP had with this `oSheet.Cells[i, 1] != null`
is that he is checking the Range which won't be null till he reach the last line of excel...

Ah didn't noticed that @Erno de Weerd pointed that out already in comments.

Comment: What will be the return value of `oSheet.get_Range()` if one cell is not null ?

Comment: Well now i'm reading @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range.aspx that: 'Use the Range property instead of this method.' Either way the return value is ...Excel.Range. If you use it on more than one cell(which is not the case above) you can loop through Cells property and check every cell within obtained range

Comment: Why do you think so ? I think that the code above gives OP exactly what he wants. Looping throught rows in first column and checking if cell is empty. In case it is empty it just put 'FirstName' into the cell.